# NetBeans: PHP Syntax Checking

Tags: php, debugging, syntax, ide

According to [a poll here on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6166/any-good-php-ide-preferably-free-or-cheap), **NetBeans** is the best PHP IDE available. This is all fine and good, except for one thing: It appears to be terrible at checking syntax. I'm sure I must be doing something wrong?

I've previously used **phpDesigner**, which is a great program, but I've only got version 2007, and it doesn't support xDebug (I'd have to buy the new version if I wanted that). So I thought I'd try the much vaunted (and free) NetBeans.

But, as far as I can tell, it's syntax checking is *horrible*. For example: Note how the same file is handled by the two different IDEs.

First **phpDesigner**:

[image: phpDesigner]

Pretty obvious where the problem is, right?

Then **NetBeans**:

[image: NetBeans]

Here there is nothing but a vague error message at the very bottom of the class, and  it's not even near the function causing the error(!).

**So my question is:** Is it possible to get better syntax checking in NetBeans? I'm presuming there must be a way, and I'm just being really dumb.

**Additionally:** If this is not possible in NetBeans, what other free IDEs are available that *do* have this level of syntax checking?

Thanks for any help.

---

Some people have suggested **Eclipse** as a replacement, so I thought I'd test it.

[image: Eclipse]

It too correctly recognises the syntax error. (Makes me wonder if NetBeans is bugged.) I may just switch to Eclipse. Are there any other IDEs people think are worth trying?

Comment: There is always `php -l`

Comment: You'll want to try JetBrain's PHPStorm. It's a commercial IDE, but it's really awesome.

Comment: Thanks, but if I was going to buy a commercial IDE, I think I'd stick with phpDesigner for the reasons stated above. I don't fancy going through this again.

Comment: there is bugs in all software, you should just inform the developers of NetBeans and help the product become better at it's purpose.

Comment: This isn't a bug, as far as I'm aware.

Comment: For non-commercial IDEs, I'd use Aptana with PDT.

Comment: Have you checked if it's the same in Netbeans7? It's not released yet, but the beta version is available for download. It may be something they've worked on in the meanwhile. However, as much as I like netbeans (and I use it myself for PHP dev work), it is primarily written as a Java IDE; PHP will always be a second-class language for it compared with Java.

Comment: I've alerted the NetBeans folks to this question. Hopefully I'll get an answer.

Comment: Note: To the people who have voted this "off-topic", it is *on*-topic as described in the SO:FAQ for being about "software tools commonly used by programmers".

Comment: Im on PhpDesigner version 7 and I love it. Does support xdebug and error checking as you show above is still very similar.  Well worth the money.  Aptana is also a good choice as mentioned above

Comment: Using NetBeans 7.0beta2 I see a syntax error on both the `private $x...` line as well as the closing brace. I guess I don't view this as that big of a deal since I've never done this. Eclipse and the others simply check for the access keywords and display a more specific error, but NetBeans *does* detect the error, and it's better in 7.0b2. Do you have any more common errors in its syntax checking? I wouldn't consider NetBeans *horrible* from this one example alone.

Comment: It's currently being evaluated as a bug by the NetBeans developers. If you have an incomplete file, there's no way you can compare results. Also, I never said NetBeans was horrible.

Comment: It's a bug: http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=168350

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well it turns out that it's a bug in NetBeans. Here's the details of the bug:

http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=168350

**Update:** It's been fixed in NetBeans 7.0.

Comment: @Epoc I switched to PHPStorm and have not looked back! Miles better.

Answer (score 2):

I don't now much about NetBeans but why don't you try [Eclipse with PDT](http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/)? It has better syntax checking as NetBeans. Using the example presented in your post Eclipse will display the same error message as PHPDesigner (and in the right place). Give it a try.
Personally, I use (and love) VIM as an IDE, but at work we have to work with Eclipse and I think it will suits your needs.

Comment: I tried Eclipse, you're right, it did pick the error. Even quicker than phpDesigner 2007. Makes me wonder if NetBeans does have a bug in it afterall. Thanks for the recommendation, I'll see if I get any others.

Comment: glad that I could help. I don't think that there is any bug in NetBeans, that's the way NetBeans works :p